# How to validate that the owner of this object is modifying it? (and write a test)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, devise, bdd

I was attempting to start a test to confirm that a user can only modify an object if current_user.id and model.user_id match.

I feel like this is a validation from the model. So I might write something like:

```
class UserLocked < ActiveModel::Validator  
  def validate(record)  
    unless record.user_id == current_user.id  
      record.errors[:name] << "Sorry you cannot modify something that is not your's"  
    end  
  end  
end
```

Which might be ok... **(is there a centralized place I can put this? do I need to do anything special to reference it then?)**

Writing a test for that isn't too bad either; however, I also need to prevent the controller from displaying the form to edit form. Should I be creating a separate view or just make it part of the edit page? How can I write a test for this for this in rspec...

I might be over thinking this, but I am trying to figure out what everyone else is doing. An example would be great! I've done this before in other languages/frameworks, but I am trying to "do things the right way."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization belongs in the controller and not in the model. So you could implement a before_filter like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  ...
  private

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user? @user
  end
end
```

Of course you would need some sort a method to detect who the current user is.

You could test this with a request spec, using RSpec & Capybara. The logic is simple: you login with a user and expect that when trying to edit the info of another user you get an error message displayed. Otherwise the relevant form fields should be displayed.

For an example see http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code:edit_update_wrong_user_tests